# Android NameValuePair send values

Tags: java, php, android, json

I have PHP code which connects to MySql and encodes  data to JSON. Later I would filter it and get specific JSON object. It worked fine while I was using one NameValuePair object but now I want to use variables like username and password. Now I am getting this alert in logcat Error parsing data .org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray.

How should I change the code that could work properly ?

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT username, firstname, lastname, email, phone1, skype, city, description FROM mdl_user WHERE username LIKE '$username' AND password LIKE '$password'");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;
print(json_encode($output));
```

Code which sends request:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usern",""+usr));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passw",""+psw));
        InputStream is = null; 
        String result = "";
        //http post
        try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ik.su.lt/~jbarzelis/Bdarbas/getUserInfo.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
```

**Edited**

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['usern']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['passw']);
$q=mysql_query("SELECT username, firstname, lastname, email, phone1, skype, city, description
FROM mdl_user WHERE username LIKE '$username' AND password LIKE '$password'");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;
print(json_encode($output));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the entire code that you have put on your server  side then i guess you need to first take values into `$username` and `$password` using the `$_POST[]` method like this

```
$username=$_POST["usern"];
$password=$_POST["passw"];
```

and the same for `password`.

since as of now there is no value in the variables your `SELECT` statement returns `null` value which is sent to client in `JSON` format which gives a `null` value error.

Comment: Now my post doesn't make sense so I'll delete it:)

Comment: But still you should rather use "=" than "LIKE" in authorization. And try hardcoding your username and password to check if it prints your output. If it does, and the problem disappears, than you have problem with sending the data to php script rather than receiving it

Comment: yes i completely agree with @MichałK over here. the issue is that null value is being returned, so it has to be a problem with the sql statement or sending data to the server,

Comment: Or just your `usr` and `psw` vars are not matching the ones in database.

Comment: I used LIKE while I was trying only username and it worked fine.

Comment: Indeed problem was that in my DB password value was some autogenerated numers. Thanks.

Comment: These are not "autogenerated numbers". You probably use some php framework which did good job and hashed your password. See my answer above. Now you should find out which hashing algorithm it used (md5, sha1) and use the same to hash password sent by your app.

Comment: yea it has to be a hashing issue. database wont create autogenerated passwords just like that.
PS: this post stays or should it be removed? considering that most of the discussion has happened here.

Comment: I think it can be removed. Because my question was answered and the problem wasn't in the code but in the database.

Comment: aah ok. i was thinking more on the lines of for future reference for someone dealing with the same issues.

Comment: And if I answered your question you should mark it answered, in case you didn't know;)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment "I used LIKE while I was trying only username and it worked fine."

In what form are you storing your password? Plain text (I hope not) or hashed? If hashed, where do you perform hashing? In php you don't if it's whole code, do you do it in your java code? If not, that's your answer.

As for the LIKE - it did work, of course. LIKE is less strict than = and it generates a significant overhead. It should only be used in very simple search statements (VERY SIMPLE), certainly not in authorization.